Microsoft SQL Server migration from 2014 to 2019
We have migrated SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2019.
We have separate Windows 2019 OS Server where SQL Server 2014 was already installed with instance name MSSQLSERVER, we have used same server where we have installed SQL Server 2019 with instance name  MSSQLSERVER19 and restored all the database from SQL Server 2014.
Now we have stopped existing SQL Server instance agent on MSSQLSERVER and configured the new MSSQLSERVER19 agent with the same port which was used by MSSQLSERVER, and started the new agent - but somehow the web server is not connecting and throwing this error

Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server error '80004005'
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].

In web server, we have connection string in registry and registry read by Global.asa files
Connection String = Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;DataTypeCompatibility=80;SERVER=<<SQL Server>>;Encrypt=Yes;TrustServerCertificate=Yes;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=<<App name>>;WSID=<<Web Server FQDN>>;DATABASE=<<>DB Name>

Do I need to change any configuration in connection string?

Well, MSSQLSERVER is the internal name for the default, unnamed instance - to which you can connect using server=(local) or server=. . On the other hand, MSSQLSERVER19 is a named instance - so you need to specify server and instance name when connecting - server=(local)\MSSQLSERVER19 or similar

Thank you Marc_S for quick response I tried with Connection String = Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;DataTypeCompatibility=80;SERVER=<<SQL Server FQDN\MSSQLSERVER19>>;Encrypt=Yes;TrustServerCertificate=Yes;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=<>;WSID=<>;DATABASE=<<>DB Name>
but still same error.

When you reconfigured the listening ports for the new instance did you restart both the MSSQLSERVER19 instance and the SQL Browser service? SQL Browser is used to resolve instance names to the TCP ports that they are listening on, but it only loads instance configurations when it first starts, so if you changes protocol configurations for any of the instances you need to restart all concerned.

Thanks AlwaysLearning its work after restart but now I getting this error
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'
Operation is not allowed when the object is closed,
still we need to configure anything in SQL Server 2019
We have classic asp code which is calling db

Are you really just blindly migrating sql server version in production without any kind of testing first? You should probably start a new question with the new problem while providing code

siggemannen we are not migrating sql server version in production without any kind of testing and no one does that, I am new to SQL Server and migrating first time. First I will migrate on dev environment and then QA and then production. I really appreciate help here if anyone has insight about the error. Thank you !
